# Traversing a matrix using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

Say there's a matrix with `N` rows and `M` columns.

You start the traversal at the bottom left, and your current points `P` is 0, and space `S` which is larger than 0. At each point in the matrix, the coordinate is either empty or contains points. If the points have size `X` and value `V`, you can choose to pick up the points or not when you reach a coordinate.

For traversing the matrix, we can only go up by one row and choose from one of the three columns (i.e. `(i + 1, j − 1)`, `(i + 1, j)`, or `(i + 1, j + 1)`)

Picking up the points increases `P` by `V` and decreases `S` by `X`.

---

I'm trying to write a dynamic programming algorithm that would traverse this and return the best path resulting in the largest number of points.

I figure the subproblems are:

```
L(N, j) = Null
L(i, 0) = max(L(i + 1, 0), L(i + 1, 1))
L(i, j) = max(L(i + 1, j − 1), L(i + 1, j), L(i + 1, j + 1))
L(i, M) = max(L(i + 1, j - 1), L(i + 1, j))
```

Would that work? How would I go about introducing this to an algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways :

1. Recursive call for function which should cover all boundary/edge conditions
   For example the function call would look like this :

   ```
   function L(i,j, p, s) :
   if(i<0 or j<0)    return -1 #edge case
   if(s<0)           return -1 #out of space
   if(p<0)           return 0  #no possible outcome
   if (s == 0)       return p  #the end
   else              return max{L(i + 1, j − 1, p+v, s-x), L(i + 1, j, p+v, s-x), L(i + 1, j + 1, p+v, s-x)}
   ```
2. Iterative with tracking with (s<0) condition and you can maintain the matrix for max S and P values for each step.